# Not able to install Jitsi desktop in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, jitsi

I am working on Debian Stable which is otherwise working very well. I am trying to install Jitsi Desktop version using instructions on this page: https://desktop.jitsi.org/Main/DebianRepository.html

Following steps work ok:

```
# install the Jitsi repository key onto your system 
wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

# create sources.list.d file with the repository
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list"

# update your package list
sudo apt-get -y update
```

Above steps work without any error. However, with following step:

```
# install Jitsi
sudo apt-get -y install jitsi
```

I get following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jitsi
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

**Edit:** I used deb file from link provided by @A.B ; it installed without any error but when I run, it gets stuck with following repeating error message on terminal:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unable to resolve net.java.sip.communicator.argdelegation [135](R 135.0): 
missing requirement [net.java.sip.communicator.argdelegation [135](R 135.0)] 
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.jitsi.util) 
[caused by: Unable to resolve org.jitsi.libjitsi [125](R 125.0): 
missing requirement [org.jitsi.libjitsi [125](R 125.0)] 
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna.ptr) 
[caused by: Unable to resolve com.sun.jna [88](R 88.0): missing 
requirement [com.sun.jna [88](R 88.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4.0))]] 
Unresolved requirements: [[net.java.sip.communicator.argdelegation [135]
(R 135.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.jitsi.util)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Jitsi's documentation appears to be (currently?) inaccurate. Today the `Packages` file downloaded from http://download.jitsi.org/stable/Packages in the end provides only theses packages (in multiple versions and architectures):

```
$ grep-dctrl -F Package -s Package --regex '.*' < Packages | uniq
Package: jibri
Package: jicofo
Package: jigasi
Package: jitsi-archive-keyring
Package: jitsi-meet-prosody
Package: jitsi-meet-tokens
Package: jitsi-meet-turnserver
Package: jitsi-meet-web-config
Package: jitsi-meet-web
Package: jitsi-meet
Package: jitsi-upload-integrations
Package: jitsi-videobridge2
Package: jitsi-videobridge
```

There's no `jitsi` package.

However the `jitsi` package does exist in the [nightly](https://jitsi.org/downloads/) [builds](https://download.jitsi.org/unstable/) (reached by replacing the word `stable` with `unstable` in the sources.list file).

To be thorough, in April 2020 there was a [snapshot made by archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200427072129/https://download.jitsi.org/stable/) of the stable repository, which did include the `jitsi` version 2.10.5550-1 package, dated from 2017. So I can only conclude that it was removed for some unknown reason from the stable repository.

This former missing 2.10 stable package is still available through this other Jitsi web page and the linked URL:

https://desktop.jitsi.org/Main/Download.html

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/releases/download/Jitsi-2.10/jitsi_2.10.5550-1_amd64.deb

Or else you can add the `jitsi` nightly builds to get the 2.11.x versions:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org unstable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-unstable.list"
```

(as the package `jitsi-archive-keyring` is the same in the unstable repository and would also install `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list` with the stable version url, it makes sense to use a different file to avoid it being overwritten)

There appears to be some inconsistency between the different methods available.

Comment: The deb file installed properly but is not running. It is giving a repeated error message. I have added this to my question above.

Comment: you must use apt-get to install it, not dpkg or it won't fetch dependencies. Please also add in your question the exact and full command you used to install the package. Anyway this could also be the reason of the removal from the repository in the first place.

Comment: I installed with gdebi-gtk (GUI) - it installed 3 dependencies also that were needed.

Comment: You should try the unstable repository then

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the detailed analysis. I'm experiencing the same issue. An issue has also been filed in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/issues/705. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.